# ¿Necesito un intent para abrir Google Voice Search?

Tags: java, android

Necesito un intent para abrir ***Google voice search*** por un boton, para eso necesito colocar un Intent en el ***MainActivity***.

```
Intent open3 = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.VoiceSearchActivity");
    startActivity(open3);
```

Intente usando el *packageName* del Voice Search, me funciona en algunos dispositivos pero en otros no, porque algunos dispositivos tienen el Voice Search con otro *PackageName*.

Comment: Gracias Alejandro, es bueno que agregues lo que has tratado es importante para qu tengas buenas respuestas, solo te falta el [tour] para otra medalla!, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El intent correcto para inicializar Google Voice Search es usando [RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH):

ejemplo:

```
private static final int CODE = 100;

Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
startActivityForResult(intent, CODE);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obviamente define un código que desees usar al recibir la respuesta en `onActivityResult()`.